# Console throws "Forbidden" _layouts/15/WsaUpload.ashx on attaching a file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, client

I am experiencing **Forbidden error** in console on URL *"https://site/_layouts/15/WsaUpload.ashx"* (see the image below) when attach files via OOB Form in the Modern List (SharePoint 2019). I have also noticed that the changes are not getting reflected asynchronously after uploading the file. Should to refresh the page to see the attachment(inside the OOB Form).
Anybody has got this error & resolved?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you have the Customer Experience Improvement Program (CEIP) feature turned off.  See https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1461

> ...disabling CEIP in the server does not mean that the wsaUpload.ashx is not called. It means that this information is not shared with Microsoft from the server. You might still see oob web parts and other elements calling this on the client side, as there's no check for CEIP in them one-by-one.